# How can I get and analyze LLVM IR in a C program?

Tags: c, clang, llvm, llvm-ir

I'm writing a program to create a DFG from LLVM IR, which compiled from C source files, and mapping the DFG into a processor's different unit.

Due to efficiency need of the mapper, the program is written in C. However to get LLVM IR, most of the methods are based on C++.

Thus, I would like to ask if I could get LLVM IR representation in a C program, so that I can directly create DFG in the program, and the program can be compiled as whole.

I've searched libclang, however, this is a library that used to traversing the AST, and there is not many tutorials out there.

Comment: There's a C wrapper that you could use. It's intended more for wrappers like [this one](https://github.com/ruby-llvm/ruby-llvm) than for C programs, though, and I would only recommend it if you're comfortable writing in C++.

Comment: @arnt do you mean libclang?? I cannot find any of the example that it can create llvm ir, most of the example would be using it to traversal the AST

Comment: No, llvm-c. Don't bother looking for examples, documentation or tutorials that'll suit you, though. As I said, it's intended for wrappers.

Comment: @arnt it seems like the interface to build llvm ir. But what I want is an API to call clang to handle the compiled llvm ir.....

Comment: So, where's your code?  I'd appreciate also that, in the first time you use an acronym, you give a full expanded view of it, so we can gracefully get in context.  Thank you.  BTW have you heard about GNU Flex/Bison tools?

Comment: @luisColorado what I want is a C/C++ program to do the same as I type `clang -emit-llvm -c 'source.cpp' -o 'source.bc' -O3 -fno-vectorize -fno-slp-vectorize -fno-unroll-loops` in terminal, so that I do not need to write and read from disc....
So it is a C/C++ program that will do the same as executing clang in terminal and gives out the in memory representation of LLVM IR